# angular http client information

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Can someone explain this piece of code to me?

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.config.apiUrl}/users`);
}
```

This code is taken from user.service.ts of this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/authenticationdemo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts
I know environment.config is a variable declared in environments/environment.ts but I don't understand its meaning:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    config: <any> ""
};
```

also I don't understand 'apiUrl' what kind of method is it, where is it referenced? I am looking for explanations, documentation about it is fine too, I have tried but I have not found anything on the official documentation. Does this kind of representation of 'http.get' code have a name? Thanks friends

Comment: Check the updated answer about any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get it step  by step.

```
return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.config.apiUrl}/users`);
```

`http` is an instance of HttpClient injected from angular in the service

`get` is a function that will perform an http GET request to the target parameter url

The `<User[]>` is a generic type that says that the http get will return an observable of those Observable and it's there to assure type safety.

The `environment.config` is of type any. That means that during compile time, it is not type safe and you can access any property, even if it exists or not.

When you access it, it is undefined value, which does not throw an error. Since the service is fake and the value is irrelevant then the code works

Comment: Cheers! Don't forget to accept the answer if it's ok with you.

Comment: Ok, I try to use just "getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`/users`);
    }" and the code works, what is "/users"? there is no server!

Comment: I think this logic works because there is 'fake-backend.ts' right?

Comment: Yeap, it's the `case url.endsWith('/users') && method === 'GET':
                    return getUsers();` part

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get familiar with Typescript syntaxes first.

`get<User[]>(...)`  means the output of this function is of `User[]` datatype. The angle brackets usage is the syntax for Generics in Typescript, just like in .NET.

```
`${environment.config.apiUrl}/users`
```

Notice the ``. this is not the string syntax but syntax of string literal or string template or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). All this is pure syntactic sugar. `${variableName}` can be used inside template literals to replace its value in the final string. In this case, the code intends to replace the value of `environment.config.apiUrl` in the string.

Now, in `environment` object, the config property is currently having a string value. The `<any> ""` syntax is to typecast the datatype of the empty string as "any".

To make your code to work, you want to change the empty string to an object. Like this:

```
config: <any> {
    apiUrl: "http://your-api-domain/"
}
```

Now, your `apiUrl` is defined in `environment.config` object. Side Note: the `<any>` typecasting is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, the code works also without change the empty string and without set apiurl, this is what i really don t understand... u can try in in stackblitz